# EF6 IsUnique attribiute and multiple null values

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, null, entity, unique

I use code first model in EF6. Is possible to create unique index with "doesn't care about" (allow) multiple nulls values? Sth like an equivalent to sql command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull
ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try a direct SQL in migration like:

```
public partial class MyMigration: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

        Sql(@"CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull ON YourTable(yourcolumn) WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("SGA.Empresas", "idx_yourcolumn_notnull");
    }
}
```